# Error: creating build container: no such file or directory

Tags: podman

When running `podman build`, I get:

```
Error: creating build container: creating container: creating read-write layer with ID "d46b51efb16fd01f507af3bf70392b3c9376ba3d53b76170ab09407f097aabb4": Stat /home/federico/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/f8c686ca891a580ae2a7931da6d670266e87e79a67b96fac2f9a97ab67bd2867/diff: no such file or directory
```

What does this mean? The parent directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in those directories probably got messed up somehow. Just remove the entire containers directory (assuming you don't have anything valuable there) and issue the command again. In your case:

```
rm -rf /home/federico/.local/share/containers/
```

Comment: worked for me :)